# Set custom keyboard for android application

Tags: android, keyboard

I know that there is the possibility to set a special keyboard with [these attributes](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType). But I need my own keyboard as default. How can I do that? How can my app change the settings?

As an example, let's say: I want the example `SoftKeyboard` as default for my app.

Is that even possible?

Comment: If you set the default keyboard inside your textview, that should be he default. Found [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) article that I think will answer the most of your question.