# creating custom android keyboard layout

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I'd like to create custom layout for Android 2.3 keyboard. Where do I start? Currently I don't have any experience in Android platform.

Is it possible to hack the existing keyboard layout so that I will not have to create a new one from scratch?

Comment: Hi, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858950/set-custom-keyboard-for-android-application).

Comment: And check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Answer (score 6):

Read about creating an [input method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) on the android dev site, specifically the [Soft Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) example.

Comment: input method link not working:(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: so there is no way to just change the keyboard-layout in res/xml , and keeping default look and behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to if you still havent resolved this :)

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html