# How to use mathematical fonts in android?

Tags: android, fonts

I am creating an app which uses math fonts like lambda,integral etc in android. And how could i use an keyboard for that? plz help nothing found on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a .ttf font file with your symbols, place it in the /assets folder then use it on a TextView like this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id...);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

As for using the keyboard see:
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/ and [creating custom android keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout)

Comment: hi, I have found a keyboard matching my requirements on market can i do something like when installling my app i can directly download the keyboard from market and use it???