# Android custom keyboard shift key

Tags: android

How can i implement the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key functionality for android custom keyboard, i want to change the keys from caps to small and small to caps while clicking the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, for me it is coming but while typing the messages texts are only in smalls, and also i need separate background for each key, for this purpose me implemented `android:keyicon` instead of `android:keylabel` attribute but while doing this the problem will arise when changing to small from caps by pressing he <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, any idea please help, thanks very much for your efforts

Comment: Hi,did you get the any ans for this.I have got same requirement like this.Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you get any valid answer please ? I have the same requirements as well.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [this project](http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/checkout) of Hackerskeyboard.

it implements that exactly

Comment: thanks for your time but in that project there is no source code for that , i am very sorry for asking like this but i am very hurry for this project

Comment: try looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout)