# android keyboard 'enter key' custom text

Tags: android

How to change android keyboard 'enter key' text to custom text. I am not talking about the default values like 'actionGo' but custom string on the key. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to create a custom key board then,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858950/set-custom-keyboard-for-android-application

Comment: May be but there should be a way to put custom text i think i am not sure what this property does !! 'android:imeActionLabel'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can *request* a custom label via `android:imeActionLabel`, but it may not have an effect. First, there may not be an action button. Second, all requests of the input method editor are hints -- editors are not required to honor any of them.

Also, bear in mind that there may not be room for your label on all devices and orientations.