# Android custom keyboard xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating custom android keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout)

I started developing my own ime, but I'm stuck with the xml file. Eclipse seems to be unable to find the Keyboard, nor Row nor Key classes. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem or how to code an ime layout with java? If this description lacks of informations fell free to let me know. Anyhow, thanks everyone 
at first it shows this:

`NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.`

"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
if i set layout_widht attribute it shows:

`NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.`

com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- Keyboard (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- Row (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Post them.

Comment: how do I add \n to my comments?

Answer (score 7):

There are a few links that you can follow up about this that are on site

[Set custom keyboard for android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858950/set-custom-keyboard-for-android-application)

[creating custom android keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout)

[How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

And a couple off site open source programs

http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/

http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/User-Event/Exampleofwritinganinputmethodforasoftkeyboard.htm

An overview of the standard android input method

http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

And a tutorial

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

There are plenty more out there, I could go on for pages - do your research first!

Comment: An overview of the standard android input method

http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

And a tutorial

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

There are plenty more out there, I could go on for pages - do your research first! these does not even try to explain how to make a keyboard layout...http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/User-Event/Exampleofwritinganinputmethodforasoftkeyboard.htm
are actually the same thing(android example keyboard does not work)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858950/set-custom-keyboard-for-android-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091674/creating-custom-android-keyboard-layout
it's not what i'm asking
http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/
i'll give it a try