# how to set action listener to popup keyboard in my custom keyboard...

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

my key code in a row

```
<Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1"  android:verticalGap="2%p"  android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupview" android:popupCharacters="wW" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```

it show a popup window with 'w' and 'W' and a cross button when long press on '1'. but there is no action listener added  to those character. If i click 'w' nothing happen but cross button works. But how can i add  action listener to this character. thanks in  advance :)

Comment: your code is your value. it automatically adds this to inputMethod of keyboard . if you want to do a different operation on this key change the code.

Comment: sorry bro i don't get what you try to explain. Please can you explain a little more? @Nepster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) . And this is [full running sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/User-Event/Exampleofwritinganinputmethodforasoftkeyboard.htm). just copy it one by one and you are done.

Read this tutorial: [Creating an Input Method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)
clone this repo: [LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME)

And some links

[How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

[Android custom keyboard xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326072/android-custom-keyboard-xml-file)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/3a2896c80475094f751ef447fc9c97028bfc2265/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinKeyboard.java

https://gitorious.org/rowboat/packages-inputmethods-latinime/source/f02964264f196447b03a88591a2964b67c318718:java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinKeyboard.java

**And you can also search for Softkeyboard Android Sample at Android Developer Site.**

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:
OnCreate:

```
 mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new ActionListener(
            Activity.this,edittext, mKeyboardView));

 public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    EditText editText;
    CustomKeyboardView displayKeyboardView;
    private Activity mTargetActivity;

    public ActionListener(Activity targetActivity, EditText editText,
                                         CustomKeyboardView
                                                 displayKeyboardView) {
        mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
        this.editText = editText;
        this.displayKeyboardView = displayKeyboardView;
    }
      @Override
      public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        int cursorPosition = editText.getSelectionEnd();
        String previousText = editText.getText().toString();
        String before, after;
        if (cursorPosition < previousText.length()) {
            before = previousText.substring(0, cursorPosition);
            after = previousText.substring(cursorPosition);
        } else {
            before = previousText;
            after = "";
        }
        editText.setText(before + text + after);
        editText.setSelection(cursorPosition + 1);
       }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case xx:// xx is primaryCode that is given program for pressed key
                onText("C");// C is char what you want to write
            default:                   
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hope it will help other.