# How to make custom Text Input type Android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I need the user to enter text in a Edit Text with custom keyboard options. That is, I need the keypad to show only "S","A","B","C","D","E" and "F" characters.
Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: You can create your own Layout for keypad with your needs...and open it as custom dialog.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858950/set-custom-keyboard-for-android-application

Answer (score 6):

Much easier solution is to add digit parameter in xml definition of EditText like following:

```
android:digits="SABCDEF"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Shown keyboard will have all characters but when user try to enter any of not allowed that will be ignored.

Hope this helps

Edit: textNosuggestions to textNoSuggestions

Comment: Is there any sollution to write that programically, not in xml?

Comment: in my opinion there is no reason for that. You don't want to change in runtime what user can enter in one text field

Comment: I make the field of editTexts dynamically. So I need it. The application creates matrix, the input can be only 1234567890./- . But I cant find solution for this combination.

Comment: cell.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

But it is not all I wanted. The / is missing.

Comment: Once again I strongly advice that you define your EditText in xml not in a runtime. Debugging such a created UI can be real pain (from my own experience), and in 99% cases there is no reason to create Views in runtime like that.. If you really want to do it so maybe this would help .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789./-"));

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Pay attention to whole comment again and try to define Views in xml please.

Comment: I see. Dimension of matrix is setup in runtime. Based on input from user. So thats why I create also field of ediTexts dynamically . I dont know, how to set editTexts dynamically in xml. Do you have any advice?